# How to refresh if statement in Python Service

Tags: python, windows, service

Ok, so I made a python service that gets the current time and checks that against all the files in the directory. If a file in that directory has the same time as the current time, it should read that file and follow the command inside. For example: If the current time is 7:30, then if it finds a file in the 'Time' directory named '7_30.protocol' (probably '07_30.protocol') it should read it and execute the commands inside. It works fine if this is the current time, but if it isn't and you have to wait for the time, then it won't work. Here's my code. What did I do wrong? I have now edited to add debugging file!

```
import win32service
import win32serviceutil
import win32event
from time import *
import glob, os, dw, winmod2

def trim_protocol(name):
     return name[:-9]

class MySvc(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "MySvc"
    _svc_display_name_ = "My Service"
    _svc_description_ = "This is just My Service"
    debug = open("C:/LIP/ServiceDebugging.txt", "w")

    def __init__(self, args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self,args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.debug.write("Closing service...\n")
        self.debug.write("Service closed!")
        self.debug.close()
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        import servicemanager
        self.timeout = 3000
        profile_filenames = []
        for file in os.listdir("C:/LIP/LIP Source Files/Config/Commands/Profiles/Time"):
            if file.endswith(".protocol"):
                profile_filenames.append(file)

        profile_titles = map(trim_protocol, profile_filenames)
        profiles = list(profile_titles)
        times = [i.replace('_', ':') for i in profiles]
        HD = os.getenv("SystemDrive")

        while 1:
            rc = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, self.timeout)
            if rc == win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                break
            else:
                self.debug.write("Service running...\n")
                current_time = strftime("%H:%M", localtime())
                if current_time in times:
                    self.debug.write("Found a file matching the current time! Opening and running...\n")
                    filename = current_time.replace(":", "_")
                    filename = filename + ".protocol"
                    file = open(HD + "/LIP/LIP Source Files/Config/Commands/Profiles/Time/" + filename, "r")
                    commands = file.read()
                    exec(commands)
                    file.close()
                    current_time = strftime("%H:%M", localtime())
                    self.debug.write("Commands have been run! Sleeping till the next minute!...\n")
                    sleep(60)
                else:
                    self.debug.write("No time match found! Moving on...\n")
                    print("Standing by...")

                sleep(5)
                continue


if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(MySvc)
```

Tell me if you need more information or if this doesn't make sense!

EDIT: Opened bounty. Let's get an answer!
EDIT: Added debugging file.

Comment: Could you explain what means "It works fine if this is the current time, but if it isn't and you have to wait for the time, then it won't work." what you meant if you have to wait for the time?

Comment: Ok, so If the exact time that I start the service is the same as a file in the directory, then the commands run. Otherwise, the service does not refresh, and does not run any commands after that.

Comment: What's not happening the way you want? Do you get an error? If so, what error?

Comment: No error. The service continues running but does not refresh the if statement and therefore does not read and run any files!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First of all, add

> sleep(5)

command at the end of the loop (just before the continue statement) so that the service won't eat up your CPU in a restless loop :)

2. You load the list of the protocol files just upon the service startup. are the files created ahead of time?
3. I would add more debug information (e.g. more print commands at critical points) and run the script from command line, so I would see where it stuck exactly.
4. This is just my opinion and you can take it or leave it, but I would strongly recommend you to invest some time to sharpen your OOP skills, your code looks too procedureal to me :)

Comment: Thanks. The protocol files are all made ahead of time. I will try what you said.

Comment: Wow! For some reason, now it's working! I also added a sleep after the commands in the file are run, so that it doesn't run it more than once.

Comment: looks better :)
But small thing - you put the sleep statement after the continue statement, so it is skipped almost all of the time... it should be just before the continue statement...

Comment: I'm feeling stupid that I haven't noticed it earlier, but the continue statement is meaningless :)

Comment: It is? Should I remove it (and why)?

Comment: Doesn't it tell the program keep going (or something)? Sorry, I'm kinda new to programming.

Comment: continue statement tells python to skip the next lines and go back to the beginning of the loop, and since that there are no more lines after the continue statement (that are in the same block of context) python will go back to the begining of the loop anyway...

Comment: I see... I suppose I'll remove it then. Thanks!